# Duvida sobre if, elif e else

Tags: python, if

Bom dia/tarde/noite

Comecei a me aventurar no python recente e estava fazendo um código para um exercício simples de uma calculadora.

```
print('Calculadora simples')


def calculadora():
    x1 = int(input('Digite o primeiro digito: '))
    x = input('Agora digite a natureza da operação: ')
    x2 = int(input('Digite o segundo digito: '))

    if x == '+':
        x3 = x1 + x2
        print('Seu resultado foi: ',x3)
        sair = str(input('Fazer de novo? (S/N)'))

        if sair == 'N' or 'n': #AQUI O ERRO
            print('Saindo...')

        elif sair == 'S' or 's':
           return calculadora()

        else:
            calculadora()


calculadora()
```

Na parte do if dentro do if em soma, quando eu executo ele ignora o elif, e só executa o if no começo.

Comment: Você não pode comparar 2 coisas numa tacada só. Explicite a comparação: ```if (sair=='N') or (sair =='n')```.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, comecei agora a estudar a linguagem, dai vem esses erros de principiante.